# Javascript to show hidden div when option is selected from dropdown list

Tags: javascript, select, html, drop-down-menu, hidden

I have 5 drop down lists on a Form, under which I have DIV elements that require user input. I display the first DIV for the first drop down list and hide all the other forms using style="display: none;".

I am looking for a Javascript that will show the second DIV when I select any option from the 2nd drop down list.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Ryan Smith

```
<tr>
 <td>Destination 1</td><td>Destination 2</td><td>Destination 3</td><td>Destination 4</td><td>Destination 5</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td> 
<SELECT NAME=drop1 style="width:150px;"> 
<OPTION VALUE=0>
<?=$optionsdest?> 
</SELECT> 
</td>
 <td> 
<SELECT NAME=drop2 style="width:150px;" onChange="javascript to show DIV leg1b">  
<OPTION VALUE=1><?=$optionsdest?> 
</SELECT> 
</td>
 <td> 
<SELECT NAME=drop3 style="width:150px;"  onChange="javascript to show DIV leg1c">  
<OPTION VALUE=0>0
<OPTION VALUE=1>1
</SELECT> 
</td>
 <td> 
<SELECT NAME=drop4 style="width:150px;"   onChange="javascript to show DIV leg1d">  
<OPTION VALUE=0>
<?=$optionsdest?> 
</SELECT>
</td>
 <td> 
<SELECT NAME=drop5 style="width:150px;"   onChange="javascript to show DIV leg1e">  
<OPTION VALUE=0>
<?=$optionsdest?> 
</SELECT>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td>

 Arrive Drop 1
 <br>
 <input type="date" id="arrivedatetime1" name="arrivedatetime1" value=<?PHP echo $arrivedate ?>>
 <br>
 <SELECT NAME=arrivetime1 style="width:150px;"> 
 <OPTION VALUE=0>
 <?=$optionstime?> 
 </SELECT>
<br>
 Depart Drop 1
 <br>
 <input type="date" id="departdatetime1" name="departdatetime1" value=<?PHP echo $departdate ?>>
 <br>
 <SELECT NAME=departtime1 style="width:150px;"> 
<OPTION VALUE=0>
<?=$optionstime?> 
</SELECT>

 </td>

  <td>
 <div id='legb1' style="display: none;">
 Arrive Drop 2
 <br>
 <input type="date" id="arrivedatetime1" name="arrivedatetime1" value=<?PHP echo $arrivedate ?>>
 <br>
 <SELECT NAME=arrivetime1 style="width:150px;"> 
 <OPTION VALUE=0>
 <?=$optionstime?> 
 </SELECT>
<br>
 Depart Drop 2
 <br>
 <input type="date" id="departdatetime1" name="departdatetime1" value=<?PHP echo $departdate ?>>
 <br>
 <SELECT NAME=departtime1 style="width:150px;"> 
<OPTION VALUE=0>
<?=$optionstime?> 
</SELECT>
 </div>
 </td>


  <td>
 <div id='legc1' style="display: none;">
 Arrive Drop 3
 <br>
 <input type="date" id="arrivedatetime1" name="arrivedatetime1" value=<?PHP echo $arrivedate ?>>
 <br>
 <SELECT NAME=arrivetime1 style="width:150px;"> 
 <OPTION VALUE=0>
 <?=$optionstime?> 
 </SELECT>
<br>
 Depart Drop 3
 <br>
 <input type="date" id="departdatetime1" name="departdatetime1" value=<?PHP echo $departdate ?>>
 <br>
 <SELECT NAME=departtime1 style="width:150px;"> 
<OPTION VALUE=0>
<?=$optionstime?> 
</SELECT>
 </div>
 </td>


  <td>
 <div id='legd1' style="display: none;">
 Arrive Drop 4
 <br>
 <input type="date" id="arrivedatetime1" name="arrivedatetime1" value=<?PHP echo $arrivedate ?>>
 <br>
 <SELECT NAME=arrivetime1 style="width:150px;"> 
 <OPTION VALUE=0>
 <?=$optionstime?> 
 </SELECT>
<br>
 Depart Drop 4
 <br>
 <input type="date" id="departdatetime1" name="departdatetime1" value=<?PHP echo $departdate ?>>
 <br>
 <SELECT NAME=departtime1 style="width:150px;"> 
<OPTION VALUE=0>
<?=$optionstime?> 
</SELECT>
 </div>
 </td>


  <td>
 <div id='lege1' style="display: none;">
 Arrive Drop 5
 <br>
 <input type="date" id="arrivedatetime1" name="arrivedatetime1" value=<?PHP echo $arrivedate ?>>
 <br>
 <SELECT NAME=arrivetime1 style="width:150px;"> 
 <OPTION VALUE=0>
 <?=$optionstime?> 
 </SELECT>
<br>
 Depart Drop 5
 <br>
 <input type="date" id="departdatetime1" name="departdatetime1" value=<?PHP echo $departdate ?>>
 <br>
 <SELECT NAME=departtime1 style="width:150px;"> 
<OPTION VALUE=0>
<?=$optionstime?> 
</SELECT>

 </td>


</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example - I added the same ID as the name to the selects

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/32Ukf/

Plain JS

```
var sels = {drop2:"legb1",drop3:"legc1",drop4:"legd1",drop5:"lege1"};  
window.onload=function() {
  for (var sel in sels) {
      document.getElementById(sels[sel]).style.display = document.getElementById(sel).selectedIndex>0?"block":"none";
      document.getElementById(sel).onchange=function() {
        document.getElementById(sels[this.id]).style.display = this.selectedIndex>0?"block":"none";
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would change your markup a bit by setting the `value` of the option to the `ID` of the `div` you want to display. The code below should get you going in the right direction.

```
<select name='drop1' style="width:150px;" onchange="ToggleDiv(this.value)"> 
    <option value="lege1">Show lege1</option>
</select>
```

Then handle it with this method:

```
function ToggleDiv(id)
{
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
}
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QdkMC/).